# Google Script - Set Filter Condition based on cell value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, filter, google-sheets

I have a set of data that is the summary of a Google query, for which I am then wishing to further filter by a specific date. The intent is that a user will enter a specific date in cell 'C5' on sheet 'David Molloy', and then I wish the queried data set in cell 'B11' to then automatically filter column B to only show results that match the date entered in C5. If there is no date in cell C5, then the no filter is to apply (i.e. shows full set of queried data).

Attached is the spreadsheet where I am trying to do this.
[test data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YTdbek6Nhzk7qR1PrcRp0n3_akz13rOFsS0-EJHITj8/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance for any assistance.